# Selecting from a column whose name is the result of another select in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do this in one statement?
If I have

```
tab1           tab2
A              B
--     and     --
1              A
```

is it possible do something like `SELECT (SELECT B FROM tab2) FROM tab1` and get '1'. I tried this and it only returned 'A'.

Comment: I think you'll need to use procedures and dynamic SQL for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this procedure using dynamic SQL should work:

```
DELIMITER //    

CREATE PROCEDURE a_procedure()
BEGIN 
    SELECT A FROM tab2 INTO @col;

    SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', @col, ' FROM tab1');
    PREPARE getValue FROM @query;
    EXECUTE getValue;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE getValue;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to execute the inner query first. Then use the result in outer query. It should work then. Please make sure you use quotes characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    holdvalue table2.B%TYPE;
    stmt VARCHAR(200);
    record VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
    select B into holdvalue from table2;
    stmt :='SELECT ' || holdvalue || ' from table1';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Query: ' || stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt INTO record;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record: ' || record); 
END
```

This is PL/SQL solution.

How ever, for mysql without PL/SQL..i think we can't.

Comment: MySQL does support dynamic SQL PREPARE/EXECUTE statements in stored procedures, but the syntax is a bit different from the Oracle example you show.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html