select column name based on another select
I have set up a table containing freight rates for item groups per country.
The columns are ITEM_GROUP, CN, GB -- and more ISOA2-Country abbreviations.
The rows contain values for the costs of shipping. This table looks like
ITEM_GROUP    CN    GB   ...
100          2.7   1.6   ...
101          1.7   0.5   ...

I want to calculate my cost prices including the freight rates. Therefore
I check in which country the main supplier of any given item is located and
show the appropriate freight amount.
I tried nesting select statements like this:
1 select i.item_number,
2        i.item_group,
3        (select 
4                (select s.isoa2code 
5                from suppliers s
6                where s.supplier_number = i.main_supplier)
7        from shipping_costs c
8        where c.item_goup = i.item_group)
9 from items i

I hoped that the select in line 3 resolves looking up for the match selected
in rows 4 to 6 (e. g. CN in the shipping_costs table for item_code 100 results in showing 2.7). However, the result is just be the country-code.

A web search would have been helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873809/sql-server-dynamically-select-column-based-on-another-select-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051016/selecting-from-a-column-whose-name-is-the-result-of-another-select-in-mysql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873809/sql-server-dynamically-select-column-based-on-another-select-column and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261697/select-column-name-dynamically-based-on-rows-from-another-table-in-sql-server

As you'll find in the links shared by @Robert, you'll have to dynamically write and execute the SQL statement, which is pretty ugly business. The reason this feels so ugly is because your table design is bad. The SQL would be trivial if your shipping_costs table was 3 columns: Item_Group | Country_Code | Cost. You could then just join to the table on the country_code and get your results.

@Robert I searched online, but I didn't found those to be helpful. Might be due to me insisting in my head that I made that work some time ago without writing dynamic statements. I was wrong there. Thanks for linking the questions, tho.

@JNevill Thanks for pointing out what should be obvious. I will drop that table and replace it with what you suggested.

Given no option to redesign the tables, you can use a case expression if the list of countries is known ahead of time and you're willing to update the query when that changes. (Updating the table is best though.)

@Lidere there is a path forward without dynamic sql and without rebuilding your table, but it's computationally heavy. Essentially you build a result set that mimics my proposed table design using lots of UNIONs. SELECT Item_Group, 'cn' as country, cn as cost FROM table UNION ALL SELECT Item_Group, 'gp', gp FROM table UNION ... and on and on. You could can put that in a CTE or subquery and reference it in your SELECT statement. Like I said though, it's the most computationally heavy solution and if you are able to restructure the table then that would be the right way to go.

@Lidere When you find similar questions, it'd be helpful to link to them and explain why they didn't help, or what is different in your case. That way people can already narrow down your problem and rule out some ideas.

The answer here, pulled from the comments, was to drop the existing table and replace it with one that is more properly normalized. The structure of the new table will be something akin to the following:



ItemGroup
CountryCode
Rate




100
CN
2.7


100
GB
1.6


101
CN
1.7


101
GB
0.5



Likely foreign keys: ItemGroup, CountryCode
Likely unique index: ItemGroup + CountryCode
This table structure allows a selection by either ItemGroup or by Country to get the desired Rate or rates. A join to a country detail table can provide the additional information if required and a join to an Item table can provide information about the item.

You can use UNPIVOT operation.
If you have fixed list of isoa2code or possible update query with new code.
See example (SQL Server):
Test data:
Items:



item_number
item_group
main_supplier




1
100
1001


2
100
1002


3
101
1003


4
101
1003


5
101
1004



Suppliers:



supplier_number
isoa2code
supplier_name




1001
GB
Supplier-1001


1002
CN
Supplier-1002


1003
CN
Supplier-1003


1004
XX
Supplier-1004



shipping_costs



ITEM_GROUP
CN
GB




100
2.7
1.6


101
1.7
0.5



Example for UNPIVOT shipping_cost
select ITEM_GROUP,country,cost
from (select * from shipping_costs) as src
UNPIVOT(
  cost for country in(CN,GB)
  )upvt




ITEM_GROUP
country
cost




100
CN
2.7


100
GB
1.6


101
CN
1.7


101
GB
0.5



Query example
select i.item_number,
   i.item_group,
   s.isoa2code,
   (select cost -- ITEM_GROUP,country,
    from (select * from shipping_costs) as src
    UNPIVOT( cost for country in(CN,GB))upvt
    where upvt.item_group = i.item_group
           and country=s.isoa2code
    ) cost
from items i
left join suppliers s on s.supplier_number=i.main_supplier




item_number
item_group
isoa2code
cost




1
100
GB
1.6


2
100
CN
2.7


3
101
CN
1.7


4
101
CN
1.7


5
101
XX
null



fiddle
Or
select i.item_number,
  i.item_group,
  s.isoa2code,
  (select cost 
   from (select * from shipping_costs c
         where c.item_group = i.item_group) as src
   UNPIVOT( cost for country in(CN,GB)  )upvt
   where upvt.country=s.isoa2code
  ) cost
from items i
left join suppliers s on s.supplier_number=i.main_supplier

